# Learning for loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for feedback/insight on using `console.log` instead of `document.write` to solve the looping triangle with a space in the CS50 Mario style problem.

**Triangle loop - CS50 mario style**

```
var str = "#";
var height = 8;
for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < height-i-1; j++) {
    document.write("_");
  }
  {
    for (var k = 0; k < i + 2; k++) {
    document.write(str);
    }
  document.write("<br />");
  }
}

//
_______##
______###
_____####
____#####
___######
__#######
_########
#########
```

The `document.write(“_”)` is because the DOM trims any white space so `(“ “)` won't work - took me ages to figure that out.

I can’t get the triangle to come out right aligned using `console.log()` instead of `document.write` - any thoughts?

Cheers - I'm a huge SOF fan for learning.

Comment: Please keep your question focused on one specific issue. What code piece isn't working, and how isn't it working? Do you get an unexpected output, an exception, ..? Please [edit] these informations in your question.

Comment: [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a forum to invite feedback on how to improve working code and may be a better place to post your question than here.

Comment: "I can't get" --- is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `console.log` is not working for you is because `console.log` auto changes lines. So if you want to use `console.log` version, switch to the below version:

```
var str = "#";
var height = 8;
for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) 
{
  var line = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < height-i-1; j++) {
    line += " ";
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < i + 2; k++) {
    line += str;
  }
  console.log(line);
}
```

Tested working with node.

Comment: Thanks so much Lance, that makes sense - I really appreciate you taking the time to explain your worked answer.